# Limit of this expression?

Tags: limits

Consider
\begin{equation}
\limsup_{t\rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{t}\ln\left(a  I(t) +b Z(t)\right)
\end{equation}

where $a$ and $b$ are positive constants and $I(t)$ and $Z(t)$ are greater or equal to zero but less than infinity.  Is the limit always $0$? Can the limit be negative?

Comment: Take $a = b = I(t) = Z(t) = 1/2$. Very strange question, are you sure you not miss some strong conditions on $I$ and $Z$?

Comment: @mihaild I am reading this paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/2003.08219.pdf. See Theorem 3.7.

Comment: They have different expression from yours - it has $t^{-1}$ factor. Also, they don't claim that $\lim \sup$ always exists, they have some hypothesis (I didn't check what).

Comment: @mihaild Ah yes I made a typo. This should be the same. I have edited it.

Comment: WIthout additional conditions, my counterexample still works (but gives $\lim \sup$ of $\infty$ now). Without restrictions on $I$ and $Z$ except positivity, expression under limit can be arbitrary function.

Comment: @mihaild wouldn’t lim sup as $t\rightarrow \infty$ be $0$?

Comment: Sorry, I miscalculated. You are correct, it will be $0$ in my example. To get $\infty$, take $a = b = 1$ and $I(t) = Z(t) = \exp(1/t^2)$. To get $-\infty$, take $a = b = 1$ and $I(t) = Z(t) = \exp(-1/t^2)$.

Comment: @mihaild If you have some time, could you read the paper? That way you have a fuller understanding of my question(you know the conditions placed on $I(t)$ and $Z(t)$)

Comment: @mihaild the examples you gave all have limit $0$ when $t \rightarrow \infty$, no?

Comment: Sorry, I again confused the limit base. We of course need $I(t) = \exp(t^2)$ to get infinity in the limit.